# why this python code is producing Runtime Error in ideone?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, sys

```
import sys
def func():
    T = int(next(sys.stdin))
    for i in range(0,T):
            N = int(next(sys.stdin))
            print (N)

func()
```

Here I am taking input T for for loop and iterating over T it gives `Runtime error  time: 0.1 memory: 10088 signal:-1` again-again . I have tried using `sys.stdin.readline()` it also giving same error .

Comment: And what error would that be?

Comment: @Takendarkk Runtime error time: 0.1 memory: 10088 signal:-1

Comment: I tried that code in a python shell on python 3.4.2 and it's working. And since you have the list `a` that do essentially nothing, I am a bit curious if this is a XY-Problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: It's not XY-problem . Without list it's also giving error . You can check it in Ideone http://ideone.com/8U5zTQ

Comment: @muthan I think now code is ok for you . There is no XY and ;

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your code at http://ideone.com/8U5zTQ . at the code itself looks fine, but your input can't be processed.

Because it is:

```
5 24 2
```

which will be the string:

```
"5 24 2"
```

this is not nearly an int, even if you try to cast it. So you could transform it to the a list with:

```
inputlist = next(sys.stdin[:-2]).split(" ")
```

to get the integers in a list that you are putting in one line. The loop over that.

After that the code would still be in loop because it want 2 integers more but at least you get some output.

Since I am not totally shure what you try to achieve, you could now iterate over that list and print your inputs:

```
inputlist = next(sys.stdin[:-2]).split(" ")
for i in inputlist
    print(i)
```

**Another solution** would be, you just put one number per line in, that would work also

so instead of

```
5 24 2
```

you put in

```
5
24
2
```

## Further Advice

on Ideone you also have an Error Traceback at the bottom auf the page:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "./prog.py", line 3, in func
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 5 24 2\n'
```

which showed you that it can't handle your input